# How to pass bundle from an activity to a recycleview in another activity

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to pass a bundle to a recycler view in another  activity .

Here is the adapter

```
public class ListEventAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListEventViewHolder> {
    private List<EventResponse> eventResponseList;
    Context context;
    String date, teamOne, teamTwo;

    public ListEventAdapter(List<EventResponse> eventResponse){
        this.eventResponseList = eventResponse;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ListEventViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_event_item, parent, false);
        // Create a ViewHolder
        ListEventViewHolder viewHolder = new ListEventViewHolder(itemView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ListEventViewHolder holder, int position) {
        getBundleValues();
        EventResponse eventResponse =  eventResponseList.get(position);
         holder.date.setText(date);

    }
```

//getIntent() is highlighted in red

```
    private void getBundleValues() {
        date = String.valueOf(getIntent().getStringExtra("date"));
        teamOne = String.valueOf(getIntent().getStringExtra("team_one"));
        teamTwo = String.valueOf(getIntent().getStringExtra("team_two"));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        // Return the size of the data
        return eventResponseList.size();

    }
}
```

Is there a better way of implementing this? Thank you

Comment: You can get the bundle in the onCreate method and then pass the values to the adapter using the constructor. In your code `getBundles()` will be called every time `onBindViewHolder()` is called.

Comment: Thank you! how do i get the values in the onBindViewHolder()?

Comment: The variables are declared outside onBindViewHolder(), and you initialize them in the constructor, you can access them directly.

Comment: hi, iam still a bit confused